# Angular 2 : System import app not working without file extension

Tags: angular, systemjs

I'm pretty new with Angular and systemjs, but I'll try to be more specific as possible.

I'm working with angularjs2 and typescript. I compile my .ts files with a tsconfig.json. Here is my config:

[image]

Next, I want to bootstrap my application through my index.html with systemjs.
But my import doesn't accept init without extension (below, my init, that actually work) :

```
    System.config({
        transpiler: 'typescript'
    });
    System.import('src/app.ts');
```

I'm forced to mention the .ts extension (same problem in ts files when I want to import handmade components).
Am I forgetting something? Documentation is a bit rough for beginners concerning first configurations.
Moreover, I've got all my scripts called in `<head>` (system.js, typescript.js, angular2.dev.js)

Comment: Did you find out an answer for this? I'm facing the same issue

Comment: No, unfortunately...

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar issue, only difference is that I'm not using angular

@Nicolas pointed into the right direction, you need to add "defaultExtension", for me the following configuration did the trick:

```
packages: {
    '.': {
        defaultJSExtensions: 'js'
    }
},
```

You can find out more about [how to configure systemjs](https://github.com/systemjs/systemjs/blob/master/docs/config-api.md#packages) on github

UPDATE: comment from Dai:

> Since systemjs 0.19 the property is defaultExtension and it defaults
>   to *.js, so it isn't necessary to define packages members unless
>   you're using non-default settings.

Comment: Since systemjs 0.19 the property is `defaultExtension` and it defaults to `*.js`, so it isn't necessary to define `packages` members unless you're using non-default settings.

Answer (score 4):

I'm study the new version of AngularJS and everytime that I needed to set up t SystemJS I use this configuration in my index page.

```
System.config({
    packages: {        
      app: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
```

You need say what is your extension file to SystemJS load your modules, I hold it helped you.

Comment: well even this does not work in chrome from vs 2015. May be iis express is doing something funny. (using system.src.js)

Answer (score 2):

On the angularjs Quickstart they do not mention that the packages names MUST match. I took me a while to figure it out.

```
System.config({
    packages: {        
      WHATEVER: {
        format: 'register',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      }
    }
  });
System.import('WHATEVER/app');
```

Comment: Is the '.ts' required in System.import('WHATEVER/app.ts'); ? In the mentioned Angular2 Quickstart (@april 2016) they do not specify the '.ts' extension.

Comment: my bad. it was a typo